# Algorithm for the independent domination number

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

A dominating set for a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a subset $D$ of $V$ such that every vertex not in $D$ is adjacent to at least one member of $D$. The domination number $γ(G)$ is the number of vertices in a smallest dominating set for $G$.

The independent domination number $i(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the size of the smallest independent dominating set (or, equivalently, the size of the smallest maximal independent set).

I need a code or algorithm for the independent domination number.

can you help me?

Comment: It would improve your Question if you can provide more context, such as what motivates the problem or what algorithms you already know to compute this value.  A recent survey of independent domination is [here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/papers/idomSurvey.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, [this problem is NP-hard](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909190188N), hence there is no known polynomial time algorithm for this problem (and probably there is no way to find one such algorithm). Worse yet, as stated in that link, *unless P=NP, no polynomial-time approximation algorithm for this problem can guarantee to find an independent dominating set with size within a factor of $K$ of the optimal, where $K$ is any fixed constant $>1$*.

You may find polynomial time approximate algorithms if you are working in some especial types of graphs. [Here](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~nwormald/papers/mids.pdf) they show a (random) polynomial time approximation algorithm for this problem in some special graphs. They also discuss aproximating algortihms for some other types of graphs.